# Что случилось с border dotted

Tags: html, css

Что случилось с border dotted
http://jsfiddle.net/gar88/6nWFR/
если не видно
http://prntscr.com/wzpte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я вот так придумал починить:

```
.tbl_info tr{
    display: block; /*вот здесь*/
    border-bottom: 1px #fff dotted;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6nWFR/3/

Comment: Спасибо! круто

Comment: там правда нек-е косяки - если строк в ячейке больше одной, то бордер теряется несколько... http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6nWFR/3/ лучше вот так наверное

Comment: @eicto мне кажется или что то там не так :)

Comment: где именно ? в последнем варианте или предыдущем ? чтобы в конце не было косяка, надо нечетное количество пикселей чтобы в длине было http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6nWFR/4/